# Pokemon Go - Reassigning Ownership

Tags: pokemon-go

My friend set up Pokemon Go on my phone using his own Google account details. He now wants to open a Pokemon game for himself, using those same details. Is there any way I can 'switch' my Pokemon game to a different Google account set up in my name (I'm on Level 22 and couldn't face starting again!)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can switch your game to another account, you'll have to make a new one or get your friend to make another google account or a pokemon trainer account.